# Question on how to get back "classical" Serre-duality from its derived functor formulation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems, derived-functors

I'm really new to derived categories, so i hope this isn't a stupid question.

I'm trying to understand how the duality described as for example in *Residues and Duality* of R. Hartshorne, using the language of derived categories, gives back the "classical" Serre-duality $$\mathrm{Ext}^{n-i}(\mathcal{F},\omega _X)\cong H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})^{\vee}$$ which i know from algebraic geometry if $X$ is a smooth variety of dimension $n$ over a field $k$, $f:X\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ its structure morphism, $\omega _X$ its canonical bundle and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$ (and $(-)^{\vee}$ is denoting the dual). This brought me to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548467/serre-duality-as-a-right-adjoint-functor) and further to the text *Derived categories of sheaves: a skimming* recommended there, which really helped me a lot, but there is still one point i don't see (on page 16 of this text) -- in the above notation:

Why is it that $$\mathrm{Hom}_{k}(\mathbf{R}f_{\ast}\mathcal{F}[i],k)\cong H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})^{\vee}$$ where $\mathcal{F}[i]$ is the complex consisting only of $\mathcal{F}$ at the $(-i)$'th place (and $0$ everywhere else)?

(Obviously $f_{\ast}$ is the global-sections functor in this case, so the statement definitely seems reasonable -- but unfortunately i just don't see how to prove it.) $\mathrm{Hom}_k$ here shall correspond to the $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{pt}}$ of the text referred to above.

EDIT: I feel that my first guess on what is actually meant by $\mathrm{Hom}_k$ (resp. $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{pt}}$) was wrong -- it now seems to me as if it is supposed to denote $\mathrm{Hom}_{D(k)}$ where $D(k)$ shall denote the "derived category of coherent sheaves on $\mathrm{Spec} (k)$". So the left hand side of the above were maps of complexes of $k$ vector spaces, corresponding -- if we were without loss of generality allowed to consider everything as living in the derived category of quasicoherent (instead of coherent) sheaves, with enough injectives -- to maps $f_{\ast}\mathcal{I}^{i}\rightarrow k$ if $\mathcal{I}^{\bullet}$ is an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F}$, and such a map again of course induced a map on cohomologies, $H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow k$ ... In case this works up to here, why would this be reversible, yielding the desired isomorphism (as i still don't see why $\mathbf{R}f_{\ast}\mathcal{F}[i]$ would be concentrated in a single degree)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you believe that $\hom_{\mathrm D(k)}(\mathrm R f_\ast \mathcal F[i],k)=\hom_{\mathrm D(k)}(k,\mathrm R f_\ast \mathcal F[i])^\vee$. Now let $f:\mathcal A\to \mathcal B$ be a left-exact functor on abelian categories. It is well-known (see Corollary 10.5.7 of Weibel, for example) that there are natural isomorphisms $\mathrm H^i(\mathrm R f(A))\simeq \mathrm R^i f(A)$ for $A\in \mathcal A$. Moving back to the category $\mathrm{D}(k)$, it should be clear that $\mathrm H^0(C^\bullet[i])=\mathrm H^i(C^\bullet)$ for any $C^\bullet$. Thus, we have
$$
  \hom_k(k,\mathsf R f_\ast \mathcal F[i]) = \mathrm H^0(\mathrm R f_\ast \mathcal F[i]) = \mathrm H^i(\mathrm R f_\ast \mathcal F) = \mathrm H^i(X,\mathcal F)
$$

**Edit:** Work for the moment in the derived category $\mathrm{D}(k)$ of chain complexes of $k$-vector spaces. Since vetor spaces are all injective modules, this is actually just the category of complexes of $k$-vector spaces up to homotopy. Let $V^\bullet$ be a complex. A morphism $f:k\to V^\bullet$ (where $k$ is concentrated in degree zero) consists of a morphism $f:k\to V^0$ such that $d^0\circ f=0$. So such a morphism just picks out an element $c\in \ker(d^0)$. You can check that two morphisms are homotopic precisely if the corresponding elements of $\ker(d^0)$ are the same in $\mathrm H^0(V^\bullet)$. To sum it up, $\hom_{\mathrm D(k)}(k,V^\bullet)=\mathrm H^0(VC^\bullet)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm sorry i have to ask, but: Why $\mathrm{Hom}_{D(k)}(k,\mathbf{R}f_{\ast}\mathcal{F}[i])=H^0(\mathbf{R}f_{\ast} \mathcal{F} [i])$ in the last line? Why not $\ldots =\mathbf{R}f_{\ast}\mathcal{F}[i]^0$, the degree $0$-part of the complex $\mathbf{R}f_{\ast}\mathcal{F}[i]^{\bullet}$? (My thought with this: as $k$ is concentrated in degree $0$ the maps of complexes should be the maps of degree $0$ parts) I must be missing some basic fact on derived categories...

Comment: Thanks again! It's all clear to me now.